# Trying to write input from keyboard into a file in Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to take input from the keyboard and then store it in a text file but I am a bit confused on how to actually do it.

My current code is as follow at the moment:

```
// reads the file txt.txt 
bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("text.txt")
if err != nil {
      panic(err)
}

// Prints out content
textInFile := string(bs)
fmt.Println(textInFile)

// Standard input from keyboard
var userInput string
fmt.Scanln(&userInput)

//Now I want to write input back to file text.txt
//func WriteFile(filename string, data []byte, perm os.FileMode) error

inputData := make([]byte, len(userInput))

err := ioutil.WriteFile("text.txt", inputData, )
```

There are so many functions in the "os" and "io" packages. I am very confused about which one I actually should use for this purpose.

I am also confused about what the third argument in the WriteFile function should be. In the documentation is says of type " perm os.FileMode" but since I am new to programming and Go I am a bit clueless.

Does anybody have any tips on how to proced?
Thanks in advance,
Marie

Comment: Do you want to append the new user input to the end of the file, or replace the old file with the new input?

Comment: Add it to the end of the file.

Comment: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) could help understand what are the permissions required by some functions. 0666 for example means (in an octal form) that a file must be readable and writable by everybody (the user, his group, the world).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// reads the file txt.txt 
bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("text.txt")
if err != nil { //may want logic to create the file if it doesn't exist
      panic(err)
}

var userInput []string

var err error = nil
var n int
//read in multiple lines from user input
//until user enters the EOF char
for ln := ""; err == nil; n, err = fmt.Scanln(ln) {
    if n > 0 {  //we actually read something into the string
        userInput = append(userInput, ln)
    } //if we didn't read anything, err is probably set
}

//open the file to append to it
//0666 corresponds to unix perms rw-rw-rw-,
//which means anyone can read or write it
out, err := os.OpenFile("text.txt", os.O_APPEND, 0666)
defer out.Close() //we'll close this file as we leave scope, no matter what

if err != nil { //assuming the file didn't somehow break
    //write each of the user input lines followed by a newline
    for _, outLn := range userInput {
        io.WriteString(out, outLn+"\n")
    }
}
```

I've made sure this compiles and runs on play.golang.org, but I'm not at my dev machine, so I can't verify that it's interacting with Stdin and the file entirely correctly. This should get you started though.

Answer (score 3):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fname := "text.txt"

    // print text file
    textin, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(textin))
    }

    // append text to file
    f, err := os.OpenFile(fname, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var textout string
    fmt.Scanln(&textout)
    _, err = f.Write([]byte(textout))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    f.Close()

    // print text file
    textin, err = ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(textin))
}
```

Comment: I think explaining the `0666` would help OP.

Comment: Are you here to explain, to answer, or to solve? Wait, don’t answer! I can already see it.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to append the user's input to a text file, you could just read the 
input as you've already done and use `ioutil.WriteFile`, as you've tried to do.
So you already got the right idea.

To make your way go, the simplified solution would be this:

```
// Read old text
current, err := ioutil.ReadFile("text.txt")

// Standard input from keyboard
var userInput string
fmt.Scanln(&userInput)

// Append the new input to the old using builtin `append`
newContent := append(current, []byte(userInput)...)

// Now write the input back to file text.txt
err = ioutil.WriteFile("text.txt", newContent, 0666)
```

The last parameter of `WriteFile` is a flag which specifies the various options for 
files. The higher bits are options like file type (`os.ModeDir`, for example) and the lower
bits represent the permissions in form of UNIX permissions (`0666`, in octal format, stands for user rw, group rw, others rw). See [the documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode) for more details.

Now that your code works, we can improve it. For example by keeping the file open
instead of opening it twice:

```
// Open the file for read and write (O_RDRW), append to it if it has
// content, create it if it does not exit, use 0666 for permissions
// on creation.
file, err := os.OpenFile("text.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666)

// Close the file when the surrounding function exists
defer file.Close()

// Read old content
current, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)

// Do something with that old content, for example, print it
fmt.Println(string(current))

// Standard input from keyboard
var userInput string
fmt.Scanln(&userInput)

// Now write the input back to file text.txt
_, err = file.WriteString(userInput)
```

The magic here is, that you use the flag `os.O_APPEND` while opening the file, 
which makes `file.WriteString()` append. Note that you need to close the file after
opening it, which we do after the function exists using the `defer` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for the code examples, it really helped me to understand this problem and how to solve it.